# How to get the exit status of a bash command in makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a Makefile like this:

```
k:
        status=$(shell ./x.sh;echo $?)
        ifeq ( $(status),0)
                   echo success
        else
                   echo failure
                   exit 1
        endif
```

`x.sh` is simple script that prints numbers 1 to 10.

So when I execute make:

```
ramana@Ramana:$make k
status=1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
/bin/sh: 1: 2: not found
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'k' failed
make: *** [k] Error 127
```

Here I get the output of script instead of `$?`. And when I compare in `ifeq` `status` value is null.

How do I get this work? Also how do I use .ONESHELL directive? Can I really exit from make if something goes wrong instead of executing the following instructions with `exit 1`?

Answer (score 0):

A recipe of GNU make is generally executed by `/bin/sh`, which means that the `ifeq` construct, which is make syntax, doesn't work.

Now the bad news: what you try to do is generally a bad idea. Using shell variables inside GNU make will very likely break your program. Using shell conditionals will snap its neck.

What I would do in your case

```
k:
    ./x.sh
    @echo Success!
```

If ./x.sh fails (i.e. has a non-zero exit status), make will stop on its own. If you desperately need the exit status, I found this to be working:

```
k:
    -./x.sh
    @echo $$@
```

Some explaining:

Normally `make` will print every line it executes. `@` before that line stops that. 
Normally `make` will stop if it executes with a non-zero exit status. `-` before a line will stop that.

EDIT: The error in your code is caused by that line -->

```
status=1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Just try running it in an shell. You could enclose it in single or double quotes, but like I said, what you try to do is very "un`make`ly".